# Find probability that three appears at the second roll, given that the first three appears at an even number of rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, conditional-probability

A die is rolled repeatedly until a three shows up for the first time. What is the probability that the three appears at the second roll, given that the first three appears at an even number of rolls?

I defined event A : the three appears at the second roll$=1/36$;
and event B:the first three appears at an even number of rolls, which I guess it should be $=1/2$;
but I didn't know how to proceed.

Comment: Where did $\frac 1{36}$ come from?  And don't guess the probability that the first $3$ appears on an even round,  work it out.  (Hint:  it's not $\frac 12$).

Comment: A should be 5/36?  and how do I get b? there are infinite scenarios

Comment: You can just sum the infinite series (it's basically a geometric series).  Or you can do it recursively:  note that, to win on an even round, you either win on round $2$ or the game resets.  And, yes:  $\frac 5{36}$ is correct.

Comment: Let $f(k)$ denote the probability that the first roll of a $3$ occurs on roll $k$.  Then, you want $$\frac{f(2)}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(2k)},$$ where $f(k)$ is computed as the probability of the following events occurring:  all rolls prior to roll $k$ are not a $(3)$, and roll $k$ is a $(3)$.

Comment: You might want to look up the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). It might also help to write out the full expressions for both the probability that the first 3 comes on an even roll and an odd roll and see if there's a relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do any infinite sums.

Let $p$ be the probability that a $3$ first appears on an *odd* roll.  Then we will get a $3$ on the first roll with probability $\frac 16$, and with probability $\frac 56$ the likelihood of having the first $3$ on an *odd* roll will be $1-p$ (because odd and even rolls have now swapped positions).  Therefore, $p=\frac 16 + \frac 56(1-p)$, so $p=\frac{6}{11}$.  Thus, the probability that the first $3$ appears on an even roll is $1-p=1- \frac {6}{11}=\frac {5}{11}$.

The probability that the first $3$ appears on the second roll is $\frac 56 \cdot \frac 16=\frac{5}{36}$, and if that does occur, then the first $3$ necessarily occurs on an even roll.  Thus, given that the first $3$ occurs on an even roll, the probability that it's precisely the second roll is $\frac{5/36}{5/11}=\frac{11}{36}$.

Comment: really appreciated, but can you please explain how did we get 5/6 *(1−p), is it because (1-p)includes all (5/6)^k * 1/6 thus to change 1/6 (and thus it doesn't occur on even)we multiply by 5, and then multiply the outcome by 1/6  for the next odd number to be 3?

Comment: I'm taking a weighted average.  With probability $\frac 16$, the game ends on the first turn.  With probability $\frac 56$, the game continues to a second turn, in which the role of odd and even rolls have swapped places, which means that now the probability of the first $3$ occurring on an odd roll is $1-p$ instead of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that **odds** are so often mistakenly used as synonymous to probability, and aren't used at all where their correct usage would greatly simplify computation:

If neither   A  nor B in sequence win on first try, the cycle repeats,
so the odds **against** $B$ are $\dfrac16:\dfrac56\dfrac16 = 1:\dfrac56 = 6:5$

Thus P(B wins on even try) $= \dfrac5{5+6} =\dfrac5{11}$
But P(wins on try $2) = \dfrac5{36}$

Hence P(wins on 2nd try | B wins on even try)
= $\dfrac{(5/36)}{(5/11)} = \dfrac{11}{36}$